# SelectionFont is not a member of System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want rich text area in my wpf vb.net project system base application like this![image]

Here i try to make my own RTA but got above error my code below

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing

Class Page2

    Private Sub BOLDbutton1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button1.Click
        RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Font(RichTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    End Sub

End Class
```

please guide me what i am doing wrong and please give any reference if there is predefined tool available like tiny-mce java script for web application?

Comment: Are you using `System.Windows.Forms` or are you using `WPF`?  The `SelectionFont` property is only valid for System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: i am using wpf  whats wrong with this i have to create all my project again only against this line of code i just need text area rich text box control what  else can i do?